# The page didn't refresh when $scope change

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

The page works well as my expect when first loaded.

After a HTTP my `$scope` changed but the page didn't refresh. I guess the problem is mainly about the scope.

If I use `ng-click` inside the ion-content, my problem had solved. But if I put it between ion-content and ion-view, the page didn't refresh.

I hope somebody can help me to figure it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A scope change is not reloading the view.

I recommand you to use `$state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});` to redirect the user on the current page.

Comment: I think it is not about the cache.I think ion-content bring a new scope.Just like ng-if.But i don't know how to deal with it.